# Sharepoint Online Calendar CSS Error?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

I'm having a really strange behavior. My events in SharePoint are showing out of the calendar. I searched for my CSS files to see if they were doing something to the events in Calendar, but they aren't.

I don't know what to do. 
What should I Do?
Thanks

[image: Sharepoint css calendar error]

Comment: In Chrome right-click misaligned element and choose 'Inspect' from the context menu. This will show you which CSS classes and styles have been applied to the element in question.

Comment: @SlavenSemper sharepoint applies this styles:
"position: absolute; left: 1px;  top: 0px;  width: -4px; height: -2px;"  to a class named "ms-acal-item". I don't know why.

Comment: Check whether there are errors in the console. I've checked my tenant and I get this style: "position:absolute;left:361px;top:258px;width:167px;height:41px;" for HTML element with class="ms-acal-item".

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, you could check if there is the custom code in the current page in the calendar list.

And then you also could create a new calendar list to check if the same issue will occur.

Comment: I created a second calendar list and the same error occur, even in different pages with different calendars to test.

I will try do watch if one of my custom codes is doing something.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I had tag in my HTML with `display:none` that made SharePoint Calendar render before HTML loaded.

So, changed my tag and removed `display:none` SharePoint Calendar started to work.

Thanks to all.